# Trying to set up a simple inventory management program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to set up a program that manages the inventory of only 3 products (choice 1 is just printing facts about quantity, price, or both of all inventory and choice 2 is printing about a specific product, I haven't gotten to the third part yet).

The problem: once I enter an operation between 1 and 3 using `input`, there is no other output, but no errors.

```
products = [['pen', 'pencil','notebook'], [10,20,30],[1, .5, 2]]
total_number_items = products[1][0] + products [1][1] + products[1][2]
min_num = min(products[1])
max_num = max(products[1])

print('1.Generate overall statistics for the entire inventory (total number 
of items, average price per item, the minimum number of items among the 
products and the maximum number of items among the products')
print('2.Retrieve information (quantity or price) for a given product')
print('3.Update information (quantity or price) for a given product')
choice = input('Select an operation by entering its number: ')


if choice == 1:
    print ('Total number of items in inventory is: ',total_number_items)
    print ('The minimum number of items among the products is: ', min_num)
    print ('The maximum number of items among the products is: ', max_num)



if choice == 2:
    inquiry = input('Which product would you like information about? ')
    if inquiry == 'pen' or 'Pen' or 'PEN':
        inquiry2 = input('Would you like quanity, price, or both? ')
        if inquiry2 == 'Quantity' or 'quantity' or 'QUANTITY':
            print('Quantity of pens is', products[1][1])
            if inquiry2 == 'price' or 'Price' or 'PRICE':
                print ('Price of pens is', products[2][1])
                if inquiry2 == 'both' or 'Both' or 'BOTH':
                    print ('Quantity of pens is', products[1][1], 'Price of 
pens is', products[2][1])

if inquiry == 'pencil' or 'Pencil' or 'PENCIL':
    inquiry2 = input('Would you like quanity, price, or both? ')
    if inquiry2 == 'Quantity' or 'quantity' or 'QUANTITY':
        print('Quantity of pencils is', products[1][1])
        if inquiry2 == 'price' or 'Price' or 'PRICE':
            print ('Price of pencils is', products[2][1])
            if inquiry2 == 'both' or 'Both' or 'BOTH':
                print ('Quantity of pencils is', products[1][1], 'Price of pencils is', products[2][1])

if inquiry == 'notebook' or 'Notebook' or 'NOTEBOOK':
    inquiry2 = input('Would you like quanity, price, or both? ')
    if inquiry2 == 'Quantity' or 'quantity' or 'QUANTITY':
        print('Quantity of notebooks is', products[1][1])
        if inquiry2 == 'price' or 'Price' or 'PRICE':
            print ('Price of notebooks is', products[2][1])
            if inquiry2 == 'both' or 'Both' or 'BOTH':
                print ('Quantity of notebooks is', products[1][1], 'Price of notebooks is', products[2][1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` in python reads and returns a **string**, but in your `if` statement you are asking if the input received is equal to **integers**.

The simple and risky way, convert the string to an integer using `int()`:

```
 choice = int(input("pick a number: "))
```

Now, obviously you will have trouble if the user enters something that is not an int... To avoid that, you can catch the error:

```
try:
    choice = int(input("pick a number: "))
except ValueError:
    # not an int...
    print("Oops, I asked for an integer...")
```

Or you can check if the input is composed of digits only beforehand:

```
answer = input("pick a number: ").strip() # remove spaces if any
if answer.isdigit():
    choice = int(answer)
else:
    print("Oops, I asked for an integer...")
```

---

Another bug. When you write:

```
if inquiry == 'Pencil' or 'pencil' ...
```

In fact this means

```
if (inquiry == 'Pencil') or ('pencil' is True) or ...
```

Since a non-empty string is `True` when converted to a boolean, the if will always execute. So, write this instead:

```
if inquiry == 'Pencil' or inquiry == 'pencil' or ...
```

Or:

```
if inquiry in ['Pencil', 'pencil', ... ]
```

Better yet, make `inquiry` lowercase so you just check for `pencil`:

```
if inquiry.lower() == 'pencil'
```

Comment: When I fix that error and I choose option 2, it prints out the quantity, price, and both regardless of what I ask for. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The input() statement in python3.x will take the value as string , when you are trying to compare string with int then the comparison will fail

```
>>> i = input('enter a number: ')
enter a number: 2
>>> type(i)
<class 'str'>
>>>
>>>
>>> i = int(input('enter a number: '))
enter a number: 2
>>> type(i)
<class 'int'>
```